# Button instead of Buy Now

Tags: buttons, terminology, wording

I need to develop an android based user interface which lists items to purchase. But in this release I cannot integrate the payment gateway.

I would like to integrate a button that indicates an intent to purchase. This event will send a note/email to the seller as a 'sale lead'. The seller will use this email for taking the sale lead ahead.

What do I label this button to be `Like`, `Get Back To me`, `Quote Me` ?

Edit : Items are ready and priced for sale, with no scope for negotiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your question whether the product exists yet.

**Register your Interest** would be good if you are collecting leads for a product that doesn't exist yet.

**Request a Quote** is pretty standard if the product exists, but further contact is required for the sale.  However, it implies that the price is unlisted and negotiable.

If the price is listed, but it can't be bought directly online, I would just make a button that says **Purchase** or **Buy**, and have that take you to a page that explains the purchase is completed offline and asks for your contact information.

Answer (score 1):

First leave the text, and focus on the color- Principle: Use alternative color and Make the button big.

Second, come back to the "call to action" text- You should be transparent with your customers. The simplest text should convey "Subscribe to product alerts!".